# How to prove that function that maps elements from Z to N is injection

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cardinals

I have a function that maps Z to N.

Intuitively I know that it is an injection, but I don't know how to prove it's injection.
I know how to prove that some function is injection, but if the function has cases I'm not sure how to approach this.
$$
h(a)= \begin{cases}2 a, & a>0 \\\\ -2 a+1, & a \leq 0\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Since the function is defined in cases, approach the proof in cases. Set $h(a)=h(b)$. Case 1: $a>0$ and $b>0$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One often checks injectivity by considering $a,b$ with $f(a)=f(b)$ and trying to deduce $a=b$. In this case it is easier to show the contrapositive statement: You have to show that for any two $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ with $a\neq b$ the function satisfies $f(a)\neq f(b)$. Since the function is defined through a case distinction you have no other choice than to check this property via a case distinction. What cases can appear?

If $a>0$ and $b>0$ then $a\neq b$ implies $f(a)=2a \neq 2b = f(b)$, essentially because the function $\mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N, x \mapsto 2x$ is an injection.

Similarly, if $a\leq0$ and $b\leq 0$ then $a\neq b$ implies $f(a) = -2a+1 \neq -2b+1 = f(b)$, since the functions $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z, x \mapsto -2x$ and $\mathbb N_0 \rightarrow \mathbb N, x \mapsto x+1$ are injections.

We still have to consider what happens if $a>0$ and $b\leq0$ and what happens if $a\leq0$ and $b>0$. By symmetry it suffices to consider the first case. Here $f(a)=2a$ is an even number, while $f(b)=-2b+1$ is odd, so $f(a)\neq f(b)$.

Comment: In this case, the contrapositive results harder, not easier, to prove. It's easer prove, for example, that $2a = 2b$ implies $a=b$ (just divide by $2$, no need to invoque in injectivity of another function), that prove that $a\ne b$ implies $2a \ne 2b$.

Comment: How would you show that if $a > 0$ and $b  \le 0$ is injectivion without negation?

Comment: @Jakov Glavač I don‘t understand your objection. I proved the case $a> 0$, $b\leq 0$, did I not? And negation is part of the very definition of $f$… Or do you object to using the contrapositive?